# Can we assume the same Lorentz Transformations for $x'$ and $t'$ holds for the differentials of $x'$ and $t'$?

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

Given an event with coordinates $(x, y, z, t)$ in inertial frame $S$ and coordinates $(x', y', z', t')$ in inertial frame $S'$, and $S'$ is moving away from S with velocity $u$ parallel to the x-axis, can I use the following implication if I were trying to show that the spacetime interval is invariant? In particular, is it right for me to assume this implication in my first line of working?
$$
x' = \gamma (x - ut) \implies dx' = \gamma (dx - udt)
\\
t' = \gamma \left(t-\frac{ux}{c^2}\right) \implies dt' = \gamma \left(dt-\frac{udx}{c^2}\right)
$$

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing what the variables here represent and what the differential is differentiating with respect to. Please also note that questions purely about mathematics without physical context should preferably go to [math.SE]

Comment: Yes.$\hspace{-1mm}$

Comment: Hint: you can safely transform $x+\Delta x$ and $t+\Delta t$, since they're just coordinates.